# why there is no error output in my stdout when run php?

Tags: php

In  my system,there are four php.ini files.

```
[1] "wampstack-5.4.24-0/frameworks/symfony/vendor/doctrine/cache/tests/travis/php.ini"
[2] "wampstack-5.4.24-0/php/php.ini"                                                  
[3] "wampstack-5.4.24-0/php/php.ini-development"                                      
[4] "wampstack-5.4.24-0/php/php.ini-production"
```

I revise the `wampstack-5.4.24-0/php/php.ini` :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On or stdout
```

When i run a wrong php file  ,why there is no error output in my web ?
My phpinfo() is :

Loaded Configuration File   C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\php\php.ini

I have revised right php.ini but no output in the stdout can be seen.

Comment: `phpinfo()` and `php -i` will tell you exactly which .ini files are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if you are looking at the correct php.ini. If you are on Linux/OSX run this on the therminal:

`php -i | grep php.ini`

This should give you the exact php.ini you should modify. Otherwise create a php file with `phpinfo();` inside and look for php.ini.